# Error when sending email in Java

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have a problem with sending emails in Java. I am using the JavaMail api to send emails. I have a program which downloads an email attachment using pop3, reads the content, does some manipulation and then sends the result in an email using smtp.

The program works fine until the last step where it sends the email and I get the following exception.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.adidas.monitoring.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:46)
at com.adidas.monitoring.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:115)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
```

I am using the following code to send the email

```
public void sendMail(String strMailContent) 
{       
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    Properties emailProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        emailProperties.load(new FileInputStream("Email.ini"));
    } catch (IOException e){
        DataLogger.logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    /*Get the properties from the email configuration file*/
    String From = emailProperties.getProperty("Email.From");
    String ToAdd = emailProperties.getProperty("Email.To");
    String CC = emailProperties.getProperty("Email.CC");
    String Subject = emailProperties.getProperty("Email.Subject");
    String Host = emailProperties.getProperty("Email.Gateway");
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", Host);
    Session emailSendSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties);

    try{         
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSendSession);
        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(From));
        emailMessage.addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,ToAdd);
        emailMessage.addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.CC,CC);
        emailMessage.setSubject(Subject);
        emailMessage.setText(strMailContent);

        Transport.send(emailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception mailEx) 
    {
        mailEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine when I use it with other programs. But when I am using it along with the pop3 code in this case, I have this error. Strange thing is the host is shown as localhost even though I set the property "mail.smtp.host".

Any help on this topic is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the following line isn't getting executed?`DataLogger.logger.error(e.getMessage());`

Comment: @DaveHowes, The above line is just a logger class I used. I checked the properties that are read and I can see the correct values being populated. Strange thing is when I disable the pop3 related code(used to download an attachment), the mail sending code works fine.